# How to make conditionally render component on every tab change in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have React Native with bottomNavigator from React Navigation. And when i change tab my components are not unmounting and still rendering. Can you tell me please how can i implement conditionally render component on every tab change?

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    CHARTS: {
      screen: ChartsScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon color={tintColor} style={{ top: HP('0.3%') }} name="chart-histogram" size={HP('4%')} />
        ),
        tabBarLabel: 'Charts'
      })
    },
    ABOUT: {
      screen: AboutScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon color={tintColor} style={{ top: HP('0.3%') }} name="buddhism" size={HP('4%')} />
        ),
        tabBarLabel: 'About'
      })
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      lazy: true,
      activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#068485',
        ...ifIphoneX(
          {
            height: HP('7%')
          },
          {
            height: HP('8%')
          }
        )
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: HP('2%'),
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: What condition do you want to implement?

Comment: I need to unmount component when i change the tab, like this {activeTab==="tab_name" && <Component />}, but i don't know how to implement it, where to put condition and how to check activeTab

Comment: I have two tabs, in one of them i have setInterval for every 5 seconds render, when i change the tab, the render is still working on the previous tab

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, you can use these listeners:

> `willFocus` - the screen will focus
>
> `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
>
> `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
>
> `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).

---

Also, you mentioned:

> I have two tabs, in one of them i have setInterval for every 5 seconds render, when i change the tab, the render is still working on the previous tab.

I guess something is wrong if you're setting an interval for re-render but anyway, you can clear the interval in the `willBlur`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but which the best way to implement auto refresh data every 5 second from API?

Comment: I would recommend you to use something like [this](https://getstream.io). Also please mark one answer as accepted for further references.